# Running pudb inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pudb

I prefer pudb for python debugging. I am building python applications that run inside docker container.

Does any one know how to make pudb available inside docker container?

Thank you

Comment: have a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/alexisno/python-dev/~/dockerfile/ or https://github.com/saulshanabrook/cosc465-iprouter/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: @user2915097 Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to have pudb installed on the Docker container (this may be done adding this line to the Dockerfile: `RUN pip install pudb`).
- You need to have the ports where you will connect to pudb open. E.g.

  - For a Dockerfile: add `EXPOSE 6900`.
  - For docker-compose the syntax is different:

    `ports:
        - "6900:6900"`
- You need to add a line to `set_trace` where you want the entry point to be in the Python code. E.g.
  `from pudb.remote import set_trace; set_trace(term_size=(160, 40), host='0.0.0.0', port=6900)`
- When the code is running and reaches that point, you can connect into it with a telnet client and use pudb as you normally would to debug. In the case above, from another terminal type `telnet 127.0.0.1 6900`.

You can find a repository with a full working example here: https://github.com/isaacbernat/docker-pudb

Comment: do you have any idea how to avoid the welcome/config screen that appears at the beginning? I tried to copy a pudb.cfg into the container, but it seems to be ignored.