# What is the best and easy way to remotely debug a python code running in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have just started working on python. I want to debug python code that is running in a ***docker container***. Can anyone please suggest me what could be the best way to remotely debug this?
I am open to use any of the IDE like `pycharm` or `VS Code` etc.
Thanks in advance.

```
Note: I'm using Mac OS for the development
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not want to debug your python code on your own computer before putting it in a container?

Comment: @StephaneM the code is already running in a container , I want to debug the code, put some breakpoints into the code like we do in Visual Studio.
Is it possible in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

One technique that I used to debug from within container was to :

- Comment the entrypoint `ENTRYPOINT ["/mydir/mycode.py"]` in the Dockerfile
- Restart the container and do `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`
- Then perform pdb /mydir/mycode.py

Other technique could be to expose the remote debugging port on the docker container using docker expose command which will allow pycharm to connect to the code. A similiar approach is discussed here.

https://medium.com/@furkanpur/remote-python-debug-to-docker-container-over-ssh-by-using-pycharm-44a9b6e82206

Comment: But this technique won't help in debugging the code from any IDE. I specifically want to debug code and put some breakpoints in code from IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what piy26 mentioned regarding exposing a remote docker port, I think pudb is very apt for the task. I wrote a github repository with a simple example and step by step instructions you can clone and try out https://github.com/isaacbernat/docker-pudb

There is more info on this other answer: [Running pudb inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885957/running-pudb-inside-docker-container/51404762#51404762)

Comment: Does it get attach to any IDE like VS code or pycharm ?

Comment: Afaik it can not be attached to any IDE. But I didn't understand this was a requirement reading the question. Pudb has a text-based based GUI though, with stack traces, and some IDE-like functionalities. Maybe this already covers your needs? You can get more info from their page https://pypi.org/project/pudb/

Comment: Did that work for you @PrateekGupta? Did you manage to make it work with VS code or pycharm?